# Effortless burning equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

What would be an appropriate equation that someone could use to calculate the temperature, density, etc, of a spherical object (1m^3 neutron star/ nuclear pasta) to be able to freefall or effortlessly glide through a material (anything and everything) of specified density, mass, volume, etc, that is in solid state?

Some examples to further explain this question and concept:

heated steel ball dropped through butter or Silicon and falls effortlessly burning the surroundings.

https://www.buzzfeed.com/norbertobriceno/hot-and-sexy?utm_source=dynamic&utm_campaign=bfsharecopy&sub=0_4734225#4734225

red hot knife cuts through cheese burning the affected sides and cutting through it like melted butter

heated iron rod being able to glide through Styrofoam.

pyrography tool able to mark through wood.

The Tesseract burning through the bottom of Red Skull's plane after he dropped it.

Easier question: How hot would a steel ball of mass 1 kg have to be to be able to "freefall"/ instantaneously burn through through a 27 m^3 uniform wooden cube?

- Ignoring the fact that the sphere loses mass from evaporating or melting itself from its own temperature, and ignoring if it turns into a black hole or that the material shatters or breaks.

Purpose: i have a character that can throw fireballs that can burn through absoultely any object without limit just like stated above, and i have for a long time looked for this specific power everywhere and with the closest thing being on https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Superpower_Wiki spatial piercing. So i am compromising to finding a relevant equation that this fire ball would follow without just being at absolute hot burning everything in its vacinity. I would also like to see how this relationship works. and also as well to check if he is just throwing a small neutron star or a traditional fire ball.

Since my character is very powerful he can alter physics to prevent the ball from turning into a blackhole and also ignore heatloss via absolute preservation.

Comment: In general, all your examples (except the wood, which burns) employ amorphous materials, which become soft when heated. Crystalline materials don't do that. (And a downvote for confusing silicon (a very hard, diamond-like crystalline substance) and silicon**e** (a nice soft amorphous material).

Comment: I’m voting to close this Q because it's not a worldbuilding question. This appears to be a physics question that was posted on the wrong stack. I recommend its migration to [physics.se]. (Please keep in mind that the purpose of [worldbuilding.se] is to help you define and consistently use the rules of a fictional world of your own creation. There is no fictional world in evidence, much less a WB problem. We allow real-world questions, but they must be asked in reference to an actual WB problem.)

Comment: In order to not be off-topic to worldbuilding, You should a tell a bit why you want the generic equation and not just the result, and why do you want this without considering it becoming a black-hole or melting itself? It's too theorical that I can't see a practical reason in wanting to penetrate a too-big-to-be-naturally-formed diamond cube, without thinking about the starting conditions nor the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

- **Negligible**: In science, we cannot IGNORE any phenomena unless it has practically negligible effects e.g. relativistic effects can be ignored at
  non-relativistic speeds.
- **Force**: The sphere will go down only if there is a force e.g. gravity or someone pushing.
- **Temperature loss**: Sphere can go down only if its melts or evaporates the outer material losing its temperature. Conditions
  change continuously as it slides down.
- **Viscosity**: As the sphere looses its temperature, viscosity of the outer material will increase, making it more difficult to slide down.

**Terminal velocity**

When a steel ball (at normal temperature) is dropped in a viscous liquid, its velocity will increase until

drag force + buoyant force = force of gravity

Then the ball will attain a constant velocity called [Terminal velocity](https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/viscous-fluid)

[image]

Your ball will never have a free fall because of drag force + buoyant force

**Conclusion**: Considering all above factors, there is no simple equation

Comment: as in it is in a super controlled climate, yes there is gravity, yes that is the point, yes that is why density is also a factor and also just an approximation.

Comment: by free fall i mean there is close to zero resistance from the object it is dropped on, there is still air resistance as in drop through a cloud ss drop through wood.

Comment: in relation to this i changed it to burn through not melt through